# jquery if else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

What am I doing wrong here?  This is on jquery-mobile.

```
$('.ui-checkbox').click(function() {
if ( 
    $('.ui-checkbox label.ui-checkbox-off').removeClass('off').addClass('on')) {        
}else {
    $('.ui-checkbox label.ui-checkbox-on').removeClass('on').addClass('off');
}
});
```

The first portion works, but not when I click a 2nd time.

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Comment: Did you use `addClass` but wanted `hasClass` ?

Comment: when I click, I'm trying to remove class "off" and add "on".. and then if you click again, remove class "on" and add "off"

Comment: I thnk you should do a `removeClass` for `ui-checkbox-off` and addClass for `ui-checkbox-on` and vice versa. It now looks like you're only trying to change the last part of the class name, which isn't possible like that.

Comment: It looks like your code is missing the part where you check the state of the checkbox: `if (this.checked) {` in other words

Comment: $('.ui-checkbox label.ui-checkbox-off').removeClass('ui-checkbox-off').addClass('ui-checkbox-on')) -..???? Is this u want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your comment, you seem to want

```
$('.ui-checkbox').click(function() {
   $('label.ui-checkbox-on,label.ui-checkbox-off', this)
        .toggleClass('on').toggleClass('off');
});
```

But this is a little strange. You could use a simple class (`on`) and simply do

```
$('.ui-checkbox').click(function() {
   $('label', this).toggleClass('on');
});
```

You probably don't need 2 classes as usually "off" means "not on".

Comment: Sidenote to your first snippet: `toggleClass` has an often missed feature to work with multiple classes. So `.toggleClass('on off')` will also work. (see: http://jsbin.com/uqavid/1/)

Comment: @Yoshi +1 Thanks, I didn't knew that, probably because, as I said, toggling only one class is usually enough.

Comment: Awesome thanks everyone! The first one is what I need since I have images replacing the checkbox.. I'll use shorthand for toggleClass('on off)